# Angular + rxjs. Анимация добавления child элемента

Tags: css, frontend, angular, css-animation, rxjs

Доброго времени суток.

Имею компонент:

```
class NotificatorComponent {
    public notifications$: Subject<Array<Notification>> =
        new Subject();

// ...

    public removeNotification(notificationId: number): void {
        const notification: Notification =
            this.notifications.find(x => x.id === notificationId);

        const notificationIndex: number =
            this.notifications.indexOf(notification);

        this.notifications.splice(notificationIndex, 1);

        this.whenUpdateNotifications$.next(this.notifications);
    }

}
```

В рамках которого используются массив из моделей:

```
interface Notification {
    id?: number;
    message: string;
    type: string;
    delay?: number;
}
```

И визуальный шаблон для него (`pug`-минифицированный html):

```
.notifications
    .notification(
        *ngFor='let notification of (notifications$ | async)',
        [ngClass]='notification.type.toLowerCase()'
    )
        .notification-header {{ notification.type }}
            span.close(
                (click)='removeNotification(notification.id)'
            ) &times;
        .notification-body {{ notification.message }}
```

Элементы в `notifications$` добавляются динамически в процессе работы приложения.

Хочу организовать следующее:

При добавлении новой нотификации (пуша в сабж `notifications$`) чтобы визуальный элемент появлялся с анимацией (например fade-in).

Пробовал через css-анимации

```
notification:last-of-type
        animation fadein 0.5s
        animation-iteration-count 1

@keyframes fadein 
  from 
    bottom 0
    opacity 0
  to 
    bottom 30px
    opacity 1
```

Но в данном случае проблема случается при удалении, что последний элемент повторяет анимацию (оно и логично, ведь селектор описан так) -  [гиф с ошибкой](http://www.giphy.com/gifs/UWmeoQxlqiSY8mAi40)

Вопрос:

1. Не могли бы вы посоветовать способ описать анимацию появления элементов в рамках данной реализации (или может другой реализации)?
2. Не могли бы подсказать способ организации "времени жизни" элемента - то есть чтобы 1 элемент (из `notification$`) имел определенное время жизни, а после чего по анимации удалялся (как визуально, так и из массивов)?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/animations

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на 2й вопрос:

С помощью rxjs:

```
    private whenNotificationDismissDelayed$: Subject<number> =
        new Subject();
```

```
    constructor(
    ) {
        this.whenNotificationDismissDelayed$
            .pipe(
                takeUntil(this.whenComponentDestroy$),
                delay(5 * 1000),
            )
            .subscribe(notificationIndex => {
                this.removeNotification(notificationIndex);
            });

        this.whenNotificationRecieved$
            .pipe(
                // ...
            )
            .subscribe(notification => {
                // ...
                this.whenNotificationDismissDelayed$.next(notification.id);
            });
    }
```

Comment: чувак, без обид, но у тебя просто треш какой-то получается :D это не так делается, у тебя изначально неправильно заложен фундамент

Comment: @overthesanity а что не так? в чем ошибки фундамента и проросшие?

Comment: то, что ты это делаешь через rxjs, и кстати у тебя утечка памяти из-за `delay`. По фундаменту - тебе нужен сервис, который будет заниматься этим, компонент-обертка для нотификейшенов + проджектится они будут динамически через `ComponentFactoryResolver` + использовать для задержек нативные анимации из коробки. P.S. - rxjs подходит НЕ для решения всех задач, иногда он избыточен

Comment: @overthesanity в чем именно утечка памяти? данный компонент и есть обертка для нотификации, он принимает сигналы от сервиса. про динамический рендер компонентов через фабрику - спасибо за совет. Изначально решил не применять такие практики просто. А в чем (конкретно в данном случае с нотификациями) избыточность rxjs?

Comment: почитай про утечки памяти в rxjs и тогда вопросы отпадут :)